# How to setup "serverless" infrastructure?

Tags: serverless-architecture

Ideally I'd like to have something like AWS Lambda on our internal servers. Write functions instead of monolith apps, use any programming language, communicate via sockets with other functions.

How to provide sufficiently sandboxed accounts for developers, where they can only write "functions" and not having to worry about underlying infrastructure at all? So ideally, they'd never use a terminal at all, no bash, no apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using [Serverless Framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) with [Offline Plugin](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) to emulate and facilitate AWS Lambda development locally. It improves productivity and also supports DevOps.

Comment: You say locally, so you still have to run production on Lambda? I was thinking of having my own Lambda-like setup for production.

Comment: For production you need to go with AWS Lambda, API Gateway setup. My experience is, while developing applications with AWS Lambnda and API Gateway, DevOps is difficult. I you can use Serverless Framework, it comes with set of features, where you can emulate API Gateway and Lambda (NodeJS) locally which will help to speed up the development.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [OpenWhisk](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk) or [Kubeless](https://github.com/kubeless/kubeless) for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using fission.io which is an open source serverless framework for Kubernetes and create your own Kubernetes cluster. https://github.com/fission/fission

Or if you don't want to fuss with configuration or set up try writing functions using [Clay.run](https://www.clay.run) - Disclaimer I'm a co-founder of Clay. You won't need to do any dev-ops just write code and it's automatically live at an HTTPS endpoint.